# Grouping the factors in ggplot

Tags: ggplot2, grouping

I am trying to create a graph based on matrix similar to one below... I am trying to group the Erosion values based on "Slope"...

```
library(ggplot2)
new_mat<-matrix(,nrow = 135, ncol = 7)
colnames(new_mat)<-c("Scenario","Runoff (mm)","Erosion (t/ac)","Slope","Soil","Tillage","Rotation")
for ( i in 1:nrow(new_mat)){ 
  new_mat[i,2]<-sample(10:50, 1)
  new_mat[i,3]<-sample(0.1:20, 1)
  new_mat[i,4]<-sample(c("S2","S3","S4","S5","S1"),1)
  new_mat[i,5]<-sample(c("Deep","Moderate","Shallow"),1)
  new_mat[i,7]<-sample(c("WBP","WBF","WF"),1)
  new_mat[i,6]<-sample(c("Intense","Reduced","Notill"),1)
  new_mat[i,1]<-paste0(new_mat[i,4],"_",new_mat[i,5],"_",new_mat[i,6],"_",new_mat[i,7],"_")
  }

#### Graph part ########
grphs_mat<-as.data.frame(new_mat)
grphs_mat$`Runoff (mm)`<-as.numeric(as.character(grphs_mat$`Runoff (mm)`))
grphs_mat$`Erosion (t/ac)`<-as.numeric(as.character(grphs_mat$`Erosion (t/ac)`))
ggplot(grphs_mat, aes(Scenario, `Erosion (t/ac)`,group=Slope, colour = Slope))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,max(as.numeric((grphs_mat$`Erosion (t/ac)`)))))+
  geom_point()+geom_line()
```

But when i run this code.. The values are distributed in x-axis for all 135 scenarios. But what i want is grouping to be done in terms of slope but it also picks up the other common factors such as Soil+Rotation+Tillage and place it in x-axis. For example: 
For these five scenarios:

S1_Deep_Intense_WBF_

S2_Deep_Intense_WBF_

S3_Deep_Intense_WBF_

S4_Deep_Intense_WBF_

S5_Deep_Intense_WBF_

It separates the S1, S2, S3,S4,S5 but also be able to know that other factors are same and put them in x-axis such that the slope lines are stacked on top of each other in 135/5 = 27 x-axis points. The final figure should look like this (Refer image). Apologies for not being able to explain it better. 
I think i am making a mistake in grouping or assigning the x-axis values.
I will appreciate your suggestions.

[image]

Comment: I think there is a `mat` variable missing from your example. Also, for my understanding, you want to group the x-axis, right? What is the order and which variables do you want to group by?

Comment: @teunbrand x-axis needs to be grouped by other remaining variables that is "Soil", "Tillage" and "Rotation". In other words, if the combination of Soil, Tillage and Rotation is same, then that should only take one tick in x-axis such that the values for different Slope will be stacked vertically in y-axis for that tick.

Comment: @teunbrand I would also like to add that there was a typo in my code, which caused the code to not run but now i have corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you give, I didn't get every possible factor combination represented so the plots looked a bit weird. What I did instead was start with the following:

```
set.seed(42)
new_mat <- matrix(,nrow = 1000, ncol = 7)
```

And then deduplicated this by summarising the values. A possible relevant step here for you analysis is that I made new variable with the `interaction()` function that is the combination of three other factors.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- grphs_mat
df$x <- with(df, interaction(Rotation, Soil, Tillage))

# The simulation did not yield unique combinations
df <- df %>% group_by(x, Slope) %>%
  summarise(n = sum(`Erosion (t/ac)`))
```

Next, I plotted this new `x` variable on the x-axis and used `"stack"` positions for the lines and points.

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y = n, colour = Slope, group = Slope)) +
  geom_line(position = "stack") +
  geom_point(position = "stack")
```

To make the x-axis slightly more readable, you can replace the `.` that the `interaction()` function placed by newlines.

```
g + scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x){gsub("\\.", "\n", x)})
```

[image]

Another option is to simply rotate the x axis labels:

```
g + theme(axis.text.x.bottom = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image]

There are a few additional options for the x-axis if you go into ggplot2 extension packages.

Comment: @ teunbrand Thank you very much for putting the effort... This saved me so much time.. So the trick that i was missing was Interaction function... This is the final code..                     ```ggplot(grphs_mat, aes(interaction(Rotation, Tillage, Soil), `Erosion (t/ac)`,group=Slope, colour = Slope))+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,max(as.numeric((grphs_mat$`Erosion (t/ac)`)))))+
  geom_point()+geom_line()``` Also grateful for the axis level rotation trick.. :)